# Angular UI-Grid - Selected items not being reset after the grid's data is refreshed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I have a grid (ui-grid) where I need to update its data some times. But when I refresh the data I keep getting the selected row from the old "view". My code:

```
$scope.gridApiDfcAss.selection.clearSelectedRows();
$scope.gridOptionsDfcAss.data = $scope.data.fidSelected.dfc;
$scope.gridApiDfcAss.grid.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
```

It's inside a function (setInfoOnListChange) called when I change the value on a list in a html page:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="fid.label for fid in myFidList" ng-model="data.fidSelected" ng-change="setInfoOnListChange('fid')" ng-if="onlyMyResponsability" ></select>
```

Example to understand:

https://postimg.org/image/enkw3796h/

after that I refresh the data but the first line remains the same ("DFC_AFCRestrLvl1") (I can't post more than 2 links, so I can't show it).

That It's wrong how you can see in the debugger:

https://postimg.org/image/mu8ubc2v5/

should be "DFC_AirCClntPAnaSRCMin" not "DFC_AFCRestrLvl1" (that is my selected row in the previous grid).

As you can see in my code I have already tried to clear the selected row before update the data. I'm also calling the notifyDataChange method but it's not working :-(

Comment: You should provide more code.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033131/keep-selection-after-ui-grid-data-refresh

Comment: Hi, I'm getting exactly the opposite from your example. I don't want to keep, on the refresh, what the user selected.